# Component not injected with @Inject and Apache cxf

Tags: spring, web-services, dependency-injection, cxf, jax-ws

I have a NullPointerException on a service I try to inject with @Inject

The @WebService class :

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "my.endpoint.interface.MyEndpointInterface")
public class MyEndpoint implements MyEndpointInterface {

    @Inject
    MyService myService;

    @Override
    public Response hello(Request request) {
         return myService.getHello(); // throw NullPointerException
    }
}
```

The MyService class is declared through @ComponentScan annotation

Comment: Your `@WebService` isn't managed by Spring, but by CXF (or your container for that matter). Hence no injection will take place, unless yu setup the integration correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

1) Check if @WebService extends @Component (not sure about that) if not add @Component to the class

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "my.endpoint.interface.MyEndpointInterface")
@Component
public class MyEndpoint implements MyEndpointInterface {
```

2) You're creating MyEndpoint with `new`(check all references). You have to get it from the Spring context. Share the cxf configuration.

3) MyEndpoint class is not scanned by the @ComponentScan.